# Objects-normal file does not contain bitcode - only for simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, bitcode

When I try to build the project on simulator, I get this error :

> ld:
>   '/Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyUser-axngkxvwurxrpedhbnqbrlaspmqg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OverView.o'
>   does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled
>   (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the
>   vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file
>   '/Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyUser-axngkxvwurxrpedhbnqbrlaspmqg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OverView.o'
>   for architecture x86_64

**OverView** file is in my project only and does not belong to any other library I have used.
When I build the same for generic iOS device, build is successful.
I have set **BITCODE_ENABLED = YES** everywhere.
Tried cleaning and removing derived data and even restarted my Mac. But that didn't work.

Comment: Have you changed this setting for both Debug and Release? Are you using Cocoapods? Can you try setting Debug to NO?

Comment: For the projects using CocoaPods, make sure you set ENABLE_BITCODE = NO on both the project and the pods container project targets.

Comment: You should set "ENABLE_BITCODE" to "NO" for your target.